# Setting CMake module search path

Tags: macos, cmake

I've written a CMake module to find libclang:

```
find_path(LibClang_INCLUDE_DIR clang-c/Index.h)
find_library(LibClang_LIBRARY NAMES clang)
```

But I've installed libclang via MacPorts to `/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.0/lib` and `/opt/local/libexec/llvm-3.0/include`.  Since this isn't a normal system location, CMake doesn't find it.

What's the best way to show CMake where it is?  How can I find out where CMake is searching?  I don't think moving the library to a more normal location is an option because I don't want to move things away from where MacPorts put them, and I also have Apple's official clang binaries (not including libclang) on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [HINTS or PATHS flag](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afind_library) to suggest locations for it to search.

If you want to make a general way to include non-standard locations, you can do two things. One is make sure the users know to put the non-standard location on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable and then suggest that as a HINT to `find_path` and `find_library` with `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The other option is to put a custom environment variable and tell users to set that if it's non-standard. For instance, `CLANG_ROOT`, and include that in the HINTS.

Of course, you can do both and it would be the most general.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you be able to point me to an example module file that does this?

Comment: FindBLAS, FindLAPACK, FindMPI, FindBoost, and FindCurses are all ones I've used that give HINTS to find_library. If you look at FindHDF5, it also includes a HINT for HDF5_ROOT from a users environment variables.